# how to "SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO" on Visual Studio C# command MySqlConnection();

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using mysql on visual studio 2013 c# but I have problem to set connectionString. error 
Please help me now!

this code:

```
connectionString = "datasource=" + server + ";" + "port=" + port + ";" + "username=" + uid + ";" + "password=" + password + ";" + "database=" + database + ";" + "charset=utf8;"+"SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO;";
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

I don't know how to set `"SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"` on visual studio but error help me to check

Answer (score 0):

There are no such option in [Connector/Net Connection String Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) list.

But you can set this value using MySqlCommand instance, just execute SET statement on your connection.

Also, you can change my.ini file to set SQL_MODE value by default.